# Get raw response JSON from Google Dialogflow in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I need to return the response from Google Dialogflow API from my Java SpringBoot app. The response type for the `detectIntent()` API is `DetectIntentResponse`. This class is however produces a complex JSON. The actual JSON created by `Dialogflow` is much simpler in the diagnostic tool.

Is there a way to get the actual raw response from `Dialogflow` API instead of parsing the `DetectIntentResponse` class because it retains the long nesting of fields which I don't want?

Sample code from Google used - [https://github.com/googleapis/DetectIntentTexts.java](https://github.com/googleapis/java-dialogflow/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DetectIntentTexts.java)

Dialogflow Diagnostic tool raw response -
Reference - [dialogflow-reference-DetectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse)

```
{
  "responseId": "856510ca-f617-4e25-b0bb-a26c0a59e030-19db3199",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "I know french",
    "parameters": {
      "language": "French",
      "language-programming": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Wow! I didn't know you knew French. How long have you known French?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Wow! I didn't know you knew French. How long have you known French?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/project-id/agent/sessions/123456789/contexts/set-language-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          "language": "French",
          "language.original": "french",
          "language-programming": "",
          "language-programming.original": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/project-id/agent/intents/fe45022f-e58a-484f-96e8-1cbd6628f648",
      "displayName": "set-language"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

I want the response to be exactly like this instead of all the extra fields that come with the `DetectIntentResponse` Java class - basically remove all unset fields and nesting of objects.

Response on parsing the `DetectIntentResponse` class directly to JSON -

```
query_result {
  query_text: "testing testing 123 abc@gmail.com"
  action: "test"
  parameters {
    fields {
      key: "email"
      value {
        string_value: "abc@gmail.com"
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "number-integer"
      value {
        list_value {
          values {
            number_value: 123.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  all_required_params_present: true
  fulfillment_text: "testing invoked"
  fulfillment_messages {
    text {
      text: "testing invoked"
    }
  }
  output_contexts {
    name: "projects/*****/agent/sessions/session-test/contexts/testing-context"
    lifespan_count: 5
    parameters {
      fields {
        key: "email"
        value {
          string_value: "abc@gmail.com"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "email.original"
        value {
          string_value: "abc@gmail.com"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "number-integer"
        value {
          list_value {
            values {
              number_value: 123.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "number-integer.original"
        value {
          string_value: "123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  intent {
    name: "projects/*****/agent/intents/*****"
    display_name: "test"
  }
  intent_detection_confidence: 1.0
  language_code: "en"
}
```

I need to get rid of the `fields`, `key`, `value`, `string_value`, `list_value` and all such additional fields to get the original raw response.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a sample response from the Dialogflow diagnostic tool that your are pertaining to? If possible provide a sample for `DetectIntentRespose` so a side by side comparison can be done.

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the JSON you get from [DetectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse)?

Comment: @RiccoD, I have added the raw response which I need. And yes, the JSON is from https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse

Comment: Based from the JSON in your question, I don't see the difference with [DetectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse).  It seems that it has the same fields and structure. Can you provide the differences you see? What fields/objects are you pertaining to when you said "basically remove all unset fields and nesting of objects"?

Comment: @RiccoD, I have added a sample JSON which is produced on directly parsing the DetectIntentResponse class

Comment: I can now see the difference. If you want the same structure from "DetectIntentResponse", what you can do is send HTTP requests using Java to [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) endpoint instead of using the Dialogflow Java client library.

Comment: Sending the HTTP request in Java will be similar with using curl. `curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/your-project-id/agent/sessions/12345657:detectIntent \
    -d "{'queryInput': {'text': {'text': 'This is a test','languageCode': 'en-US'}}}"` This will give you "DetetectIntentResponse"  JSON structure.

Comment: @RiccoD, I found a solution to do it without explicitly calling the API. Thank you for your help. I will try this out, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through some documentation, I found the prefect solution.

There's a Google library which can be added as a dependency in the app and it parses the response from `DetectIntentResponse` object to original raw response JSON.

**build.gradle**

`implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:4.0.0-rc-2'`

**detectIntent()**

```
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;

DetectIntentResponse response = sessionClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
return JsonFormat.printer().print(response);
```